# How to fix problem with bootstrap album grid system

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am facing a problem with the Bootstrap-4 grid system.
I want to write for each and use one container and add elements from the database automatically.
When I use `th:each` loop, it brakes the Bootsytap grid system.
I want to be like this ...

[image]

but I receive this when I use the loop ...

[image]

This is my code:

```
<span th:each="el:${base}">

<div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-4 ">

                <div class="card mb-4 shadow-lg ">
                    <svg>
                        <image th:href="@{'/img/' + ${el.imgName}}" width="100%" height="100%"
                               preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" th:alt="error"/>
                    </svg>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p th:text="${el.imgDesc}" class="card-text"></p>
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                            </div>
                            <small class="text-muted"></small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>

</div>
</span>
```

And this is the code of bootstrap grid:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="225" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Thumbnail"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">Thumbnail</text></svg>
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
            </div>
            <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are repeating `<div class="row">` and this is why each card displayed in its own row. Instead, you should be repeating `<div class="col-md-4">` to get the same HTML output as in your Bootstrap example. So your code may look like ...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4" th:each="el:${base}">

            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-lg ">
                <svg>
                    <image th:href="@{'/img/' + ${el.imgName}}" width="100%" height="100%"
                           preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" th:alt="error"/>
                </svg>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p th:text="${el.imgDesc}" class="card-text"></p>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                        </div>
                        <small class="text-muted"></small>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: THANKSSSS AAA LOTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT Slava Ibanov it worked